# Error when creating vehicles and locations

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-vehicle-routing

We are running OptaWeb Vehicle Routing and creating vehicles and locations. Some times we get the following error:

`The workingObjects (PlanningVehicle{capacity=20,depot=1,id=9}, PlanningVehicle{capacity=20,depot=1,id=9}) have the same planningId ((class org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.domain.PlanningVehicle,9)). Working objects must be unique.`

Stack trace is the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when creating location
  at org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.websocket.VRPController.addLocation(VRPController.java:75)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The workingObjects (PlanningVehicle{capacity=20,depot=1,id=9}, PlanningVehicle{capacity=20,depot=1,id=9}) have the same planningId ((class org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.domain.PlanningVehicle,9)). Working objects must be unique.
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.addWorkingObject(PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.java:41)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.addWorkingObject(LookUpManager.java:49)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.resetWorkingObjects(LookUpManager.java:43)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:169)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(DroolsScoreDirector.java:66)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.setWorkingSolutionFromBestSolution(DefaultSolverScope.java:218)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.solvingStarted(AbstractSolver.java:79)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solvingStarted(DefaultSolver.java:208)
  at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:188)
  at org.optaweb.vehiclerouting.plugin.planner.SolverManager.lambda$startSolver$0(SolverManager.java:100)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:275)
  ... 1 more
',
```

It seems to be random and we can't find a solution. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share the exception stack trace? On which occasion does it happen? When doing real-time changes like adding/removing vehicles? And what is the OptaWeb version that you are using?

Comment: I've added the stack trace above.
The VRPController is a duplicate of WebSocketController, but instead of sockets it uses REST API.
This occasion happens when adding locations. The OptaWeb version is **7.35.0.Final**.

Comment: Thanks, the stack trace is helpful. It doesn't make sense at first sight because it seems a vehicle is being added during `VRPController.addLocation()` but after a second thought I think what's going on is that adding the location fails because the solver has already crashed previously when a *wrong* vehicle was added. You should investigate the way you're adding new vehicles. For some reason you've tried to add two vehicles with the same ID (or one vehicle twice). Sharing more of your code customization could help. You could also try to create a reproducer on the upstream repo and send a PR.

Comment: Yes, I was adding new vehicles and addresses in parallel and now I wait for the previous one to be added so that was the problem! Thank you!